# What physiological effect takes away my knee pain when squatting?

Tags: squats, pain, knee-pain

A bit of pretext: I've been having sporadic knee pains (left side) for the last 6 years now. I could never do any leg cardio like running or cycling. I went to four physicians/orthopedics, was x-rayed 2 times and went through 2 MRTs, with no results other then "you're still young and untrained, take it slow". The problem was no matter how slow I took it, my knee would hurt after, but seldom during, the exercise.

One day, some months ago I decided to screw it and go all out. Recklessly, I loaded up my barbell and started squatting. A funny thing happened, as my knees actually felt very healthy during the movement. What's more, my knees felt better the day *after* the squats too, and even more so as I progressed in weight lifted.

Six months later, I'm still having the occasional knee pain, but much less then before. Also, if I have this pain and do 3-5 bodyweight squats with good form, it goes away and stays away for several hours. It also works with back pain (from sleeping on a sofa, for example). Now there has to be some explanation, some physiological effect that I do not yet understand. If anyone could help me out and explain to me *why* squatting helps alleviate knee and back pain, I could probably use that effect more efficiently in the future.

Comment: I just want to recommend [this](http://www.runningwritings.com/2011/09/injury-series-tendon-remodeling-part-ii.html) article because it helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LarissaGodzilla, 
 
Reading and anecdotal experiences have shown that weight squatting helps with knee pains. 
 
While i can't give a resource-backed answer at the moment, my theory is that:

- Squatting improves the strength of your body, including your thighs, overall legs, and body. Because the legs are now stronger, the muscles are more able to sustain the weight of the  legs and that reduces the pressure on the knee joints.

If i can find a resource to back up the theory, i will update my answer with it. 
 
Keep squatting :).

Comment: Yeah, the 'getting stronger over time' part makes sense. What I'm still wondering about is, why the pain goes away immediately when squatting.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla If you've performed pushups or pullups, you should immediately feel an increase in your chest size after the exercise. Those muscles are temporarily hyper-activated. I suspect it's similar to the thigh muscles after squatting. The temporary *hyper-activated* effect on the thighs reduces the weight from your knee caps. Without a source proving otherwise, that's what I believe happened :).

Comment: Sounds reasonable. That would also explain why higher weight has a better effect (more pump, more stabilisation).

Comment: Strengthening the leg muscle around the knee will most definitely help to support the knee and help over time.  Could it be the bodies natural endorphins that are kicking in whilst you are exercising?   A little surprised it doesn't seem to hurt the next day though.

Comment: Great that it doesn't though - enjoy your progress!

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive: Sorry, I didn't notice your comments till now. I don't think it's endorphins, as the pain stays away considerably longer than I'd expect if endorphins were the reason. Also 3-5 bodyweight squats in the office don't normally give me an endorphin-rush ;)

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla - no, if you are getting relief by just doing 3-5 body weight squats, it's certainly isn't endorphins.  My only other thought, is it could simply be that by doing the exercise you are generating more synovial fluid around the knee joint lubricating the knee. http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-synovial-fluid.htm

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive: I had that theory too, some time ago. I discarded it because 'air-cycling' (lying on your back, doing cycling movements in the air) should have had the same effect, but didn't.